# Can't hide other elements while clicking on another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a toggle which works, but every element I click on creates a stack of these showed elements. Instead I'm trying to hide everything and display only element that I clicked on. Now I can only hide it when I click on the same element twice, which is not what I want. I want to click on one and hide previous ones that were showing.

`.totalpoll-choice-image-2` is a bunch of images that always has to be shown. They are what the user clicks on to display hidden description under each image. That description shows up when I click on `.totalpoll-choice-image-2`. There are 5 images with that class. The next image I click on, I want to hide the previous description box.

My code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName("totalpoll-choice-image-2");
  var elements = Array.prototype.slice.call(Array.from( element ) );
  console.log(elements);
  jQuery(element).each(function(item) {
    jQuery(this).unbind('click').click(function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      var id = jQuery(this).attr("data-id");
      console.log(this);
      //jQuery("#" + id).css({"display": 'block !important'});
      //document.getElementById(id).style.setProperty( 'display', 'block', 'important' );

      var descriptionContainer = document.getElementById(id);

      var thiss = jQuery(this);
      console.log(thiss);
      console.log(jQuery(descriptionContainer).not(thiss).hide());
      jQuery(descriptionContainer).toggleClass("show");

    });
  })
})
```

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why are you doing things like `document.getElementsByClassName("totalpoll-choice-image-2")` and `document.getElementById(id)`?

Comment: @j08691 It was all vanilla code at first and then I changed to jquery, so that's probably how I left it off. Does it make difference? Can't I mix some vanilla with jquery? I mean it works

Comment: Usually in jQuery, you don't want/need to attach event handlers inside a loop.

Comment: Are you trying to show only the clicked `.totalpoll-choice-image-2` and hide all the other `.totalpoll-choice-image-2` ?

Comment: @Mikey But it's an array. Event listeners doesn't work on array without loop.

Comment: @Mikey `.totalpoll-choice-image-2` is a bunch of images that always has to be shown. They are what the user clicks on to display hidden description under each image. That description shows up when I click on ` .totalpoll-choice-image-2`. There are 5 images with that class. The next image I click on, I want to hide the previous description box.

Comment: @Limpuls Ah, now that makes your question and code a lot more clear.

Comment: @Mikey I'm sorry if it wasn't clear at first. I'm still learning to ask quality questions on SO. I would have included some HTML to make it easier to understand, but it's all wordpress plugin generated html and copying it from chrome dev tools would be a mess.

Comment: I don't think I have time to write out an answer but things like this are usually done by adding and removing classes. So your default class on your descriptions have display:none;. Now to show a single description you add a class .showDesc{ display:block;} to the description that was clicked on. When you do this you also remove .showDesc from all other elements (Do this before you add this class to the clicked element of course or else it will undo the show work).

Comment: @ElijahTate Yes, that's why I created this question. I already did the toggle class and it works fine. Now I just need to do the second part and hide other desription on click to display only one. And that's what I'm struggling with. You say "remove .showDesc from all other elements". How do I do that? Run another loop inside and toggle class `hide` for them? How do I make sure that the loop doesn't hide current item?

Comment: I agree with Mikey.  There is no need for the loop to bind the event handler to the elements.  `$(selector).on()` (and `off`) implicitly loops over each of the elements in the result stack and binds on them.  I see no reason with what you are doing in the binding that you must write the looping yourself.

Comment: "Event listeners doesn't work on array without loop" No but `jQuery(".totalpoll-choice-image-2").unbind('click').click(function(e)` would bind to all of them at once (although you should use .off() because .unbind() is deprecated) with no need for a loop.

Comment: Dummy example of using the implicit loop binding.  https://jsfiddle.net/0wr2s377/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach event handlers to a group of DOM elements at once with jQuery. So in this case, mixing vanilla JS with jQuery isn't doing you any favors - though it is possible.

I threw together this little example of what it sounds like you're going for. 
The script itself is very simple (shown below). The classes and IDs are different, but the idea should be the same:

```
// Assign click handlers to all items at once
$('.img').click(function(e){
  // Turn off all the texts
  $('.stuff').hide();
  // Show the one you want
  $('#' + $(e.target).data('id')).show();
})
```

https://codepen.io/meltingchocolate/pen/NyzKMp

You may also note that I extracted the ID from the data-id attribute using the [.data() method](https://api.jquery.com/data/#data2), and attached the event listener with the [.click() method](https://api.jquery.com/click/). This is the typical way to apply event handlers across a group of jQuery objects.

Comment: Your example worked great. The only problem I ran into is that even tho `.totalpoll-choice-image-2` wraps the img tag, I still can't click on the img, event handler does nothing, I need to click a little bit outside img but still inside `.totalpoll-choice-image-2` for event handler to work. Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: The event target would be different. The click event will "bubble up" to the wrapper class and execute the handler, but the event target `e.target` would be different (it would be the image rather than the wrapper) - so it wouldn't find the ID. You could fix that by moving the data-id to the image itself.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood based on your comments you want to show only description of image that has been clicked.
Here is my solution

```
$('.container').on('click', 'img', function() {
 $(this).closest('.container').find('.image-description').addClass('hidden');
 $(this).siblings('p').removeClass('hidden');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rtsj6r41/

Also please mind your jquery version, because unbind() is deprecated since 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation so that you only add your event handler once to the parent of your images. This is usually the best method for keeping work the browser has to do down. Adding and removing classes is a clean method for show and hide, because you can see what is happening by looking at your html along with other benefits like being easily able to check if an item is visible with .hasClass().

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0yL5zuab/17/

EXAMPLE HTML

```
< div class="main" >
    <div class="image-parent">
        <div class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="image-descr">
            Some text. Some text. Some text.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-parent">
        <div class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="image-descr">
            Some text. Some text. Some text.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-parent">
        <div class="image">
        </div>
        <div class="image-descr">
            Some text. Some text. Some text.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">

    </div>
</div>
```

EXAMPLE CSS

```
.image-parent{
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

.image-parent .image{
    background: blue;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.image-descr{
    display: none;
    height: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}

.show-descr{
    display: block;
}

.clear{
    clear: both;
}
```

EXAMPLE JQUERY

```
$(".main").on("click", ".image-parent", ShowDescription);

function ShowDescription(e) {
    var $parent = $(e.target).parent(".image-parent");
    var $desc = $parent.find(".image-descr");

    $(".image-descr").removeClass("show-descr");
    $desc.addClass("show-descr");
}
```